# methods to import deposits and trades

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I run a large scaled app much larger than I can handle or develop for, website grew out of control and currently has over 22000 users.

We support importing from different APIs, each import is split into 6 functions, I would appreciate if someone could tell me what I could improve in this code to make it more efficient, I am in the middle of doing a lot of optimizations to make it so we don't have to get a more expensive server.

Here are the functions, I have plenty more but I would like to see if its even possible to help me first:

```
public function importDepositsB($userid)
    {
      // This get's the API key combination
      if(Key::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->exists())
      {
        $key = Key::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->first();
      } else
      {
        event(new PushEvent('No API keys found, please add your Bittrex API keys.', 'error', $userid));

        // This is a cache key which makes sure that not more than 1 import is running at a time
        Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
        die("No API keys found, please add your Bittrex API keys.");
      }

      // Decrypt the API keys
      $apikey = decrypt($key->public);
      $apisecret = decrypt($key->private);

      // This gets the data from the API.
      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      try{
      $nonce=time();
      $uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getdeposithistory?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
      $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
      $res = $client->request('GET', $uri, [
      'headers' => [
      'apisign' => $sign,
      ]]);
      $response = $res->getBody();
      $deposits = json_decode($response, true);
      if($deposits['success'] == "true")
      {
        // Send a push notification to the user that the import has started
        event(new PushEvent('Your import has started!', 'success', $userid));

        // Loop through the data we received from the API.
      foreach($deposits['result'] as $d)
      {
        $ddate = strtotime($d['LastUpdated']);
        $newformat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ddate);
        $newformat2 = date('Y-m-d', $ddate);

        // This renames the Currency to work properly with updates names and such.
        if($d['Currency'] == "ANS")
        {
          $d['Currency'] = "NEO";
        } elseif($d['Currency'] == "BCC") {
          $d['Currency'] = "BCH";
        } elseif($d['Currency'] == "SEC") {
          $d['Currency'] = "SAFEX";
        }

        // This makes sure that the imported data has not been processed in a previous import.
        if(!Deposit::where('txid', $userid . $d['TxId'])->exists())
        {
          // Get bitcoin price of day:
            $historical = History::getHistorical($newformat);
            $btc_usd = $historical->USD;
            $btc_eur = $historical->USD * Multiplier::where('currency', 'EUR')->select('price')->first()->price;
            $btc_gbp = $historical->USD * Multiplier::where('currency', 'GBP')->select('price')->first()->price;
            $btc_usdt = $historical->USD;
            $btc_eth = $historical->ETH;
            $value = 0;

            // This gets historical prices
            $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
            $res = $client->request('GET', 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnChartData&currencyPair=BTC_'.$d['Currency'].'&start='.strtotime($newformat2).'&end='.strtotime($newformat2).'&period=14400');
            $response = $res->getBody();
            $prices = json_decode($response, true);

            if($d['Currency'] != "BTC")
            {
              foreach($prices as $price)
              {
                if(is_array($prices) && isset($price['open']))
                {
                  $value = $price['open'];
                } else {
                  $value = 0;
                }
              }
            } else {
              $value = 1;
            }



        // Insert the deposit to the database
        $deposit = new Deposit;
        $deposit->userid = $userid;
        $deposit->exchange = "Bittrex";
        $deposit->txid = $userid . $d['TxId'];
        $deposit->date = $newformat;
        $deposit->currency = $d['Currency'];
        $deposit->amount = $d['Amount'];
        $deposit->btc_price_deposit_usd = $btc_usd;
        $deposit->btc_price_deposit_eur = $btc_eur;
        $deposit->btc_price_deposit_gbp = $btc_gbp;
        $deposit->btc_price_deposit_eth = $btc_eth;
        $deposit->btc_price_deposit_usdt = $btc_usdt;
        $deposit->price = $value;
        $deposit->save();

        // This checks if a balance exists, if it doesn't we create a new balance
        if(!Balance::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['currency', '=', $d['Currency']], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->exists())
        {
          $balance = new Balance;
          $balance->exchange = "Bittrex";
          $balance->userid = $userid;
          $balance->currency = $d['Currency'];
          $balance->amount = $d['Amount'];
          $balance->save();
        } else
        {
          $balance = Balance::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['currency', '=', $d['Currency']], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->first();
          $balance->amount += $d['Amount'];
          $balance->save();
        }

        }

      }
      } else {

        // Here is some fallback stuff
        if($deposits['message'] == "APIKEY_INVALID")
        {
          Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
          event(new PushEvent('No API keys found or invalid combination.', 'error', $userid));
          abort(403);
        } else {
          Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
          event(new PushEvent($deposits['message'], 'error', $userid));
          abort(403);
        }
        }
      } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $e){
        event(new PushEvent('No API keys found or invalid combination.', 'error', $userid));
        Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
      } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
        event(new PushEvent('No API keys found or invalid combination.', 'error', $userid));
        Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
      } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\BadResponseException $e) {
        event(new PushEvent('No API keys found or invalid combination.', 'error', $userid));
        Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
      } catch(\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $e) {
        event(new PushEvent('No API keys found or invalid combination.', 'error', $userid));
        Cache::forget('Import-Bittrex2'.$userid);
      }
    }
```

Here is the import trade function:

```
public function importTradesB($userid)
    {
      // User Variables
      $user = User::where('id', $userid)->first();
      $key = Key::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->first();
      $apikey = decrypt($key->public);
      $apisecret = decrypt($key->private);
      $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
      try{
      $nonce=time();
      $uri='https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/account/getorderhistory?apikey='.$apikey.'&nonce='.$nonce;
      $sign=hash_hmac('sha512',$uri,$apisecret);
      $res = $client->request('GET', $uri, [
      'headers' => [
      'apisign' => $sign,
      ]]);
      $response = $res->getBody();
      $trades = json_decode($response, true);
      }  catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
      }



      foreach($trades['result'] as $trade)
      {
        if(!BittrexTrade::where('tradeid', $userid . $trade['OrderUuid'])->exists())
        {
          $currencies = explode("-", $trade['Exchange']);

          $ddate = strtotime($trade['TimeStamp']);
          $newformat = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $ddate);

          $t = new BittrexTrade;
          $t->userid = $userid;
          $t->tradeid = $userid . $trade['OrderUuid'];
          $t->date = $newformat;
          $t->type = $trade['OrderType'];
          $t->market = $currencies[0];
          if($currencies[1] == "ANS")
          {
            $t->currency = "NEO";
          } elseif($currencies[1] == "BCC") {
            $t->currency = "BCH";
          } elseif($currencies[1] == "SEC")
          {
            $t->currency = "SAFEX";
          }
           else {
            $t->currency = $currencies[1];
          }
          $t->price = $trade['PricePerUnit'];
          $t->amount = $trade['Quantity'] - $trade['QuantityRemaining'];
          $t->fee = $trade['Commission'];
          $t->total = $trade['Price'];
          $t->save();

        }

      }

    }
```

Comment: are these functions methods within a class (e.g. controller sub-class) or just helper functions?

Answer (score 2):

## General review

Overall the code looks a bit lengthy. There are two methods - the first of which is 151 lines, and the second of which is 61 lines. It may be wise to break those up into smaller chunks, potentially with chunks moved into separate methods - e.g. one to get the API key and secret, one to get the deposits response from the API, one to save deposit records, etc.

Indentation is also a bit irregular - for example inside `try` blocks the code does not appear to be indented.

> ```
> try{
> $nonce=time();
> ```

Similar to blocks for other control structures like `if` and `for` loops idiomatic PHP code includes an extra indentation level inside blocks.

Some indentation levels exist though some appear to be two spaces whereas others appear to be four. For the sake of readability it is best to make them consistent.

## Specific feedback

### There are inconsistencies related to new lines before brackets

The spacing before brackets is inconsistent- e.g. some following an `if` and condition  have a new line, yet many following an `elseif` and a condition just have a single space. Here is a prime example:

> ```
> if($currencies[1] == "ANS")
> {
>   $t->currency = "NEO";
>  } elseif($currencies[1] == "BCC") {
>    $t->currency = "BCH";
>  } elseif($currencies[1] == "SEC")
> {
>    $t->currency = "SAFEX";
>  }
>   else {
>    $t->currency = $currencies[1];
>  }
> ```

### Redundancies can be eliminated

The code has many redundancies - e.g.

> ```
> if(Key::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->exists())
> {
>   $key = Key::where([['userid', '=', $userid], ['exchange', '=', 'Bittrex']])->first();
> }
> ```

The repeated queries can be simplified:

```
$userExchangeQuery = Key::where(['userid' => $userid, 'exchange => 'Bittrex']);
if($userExchangeQuery->exists()) {
    $key = $userExchangeQuery->first();
}
```

That way the `where()` method only needs to be called once and can still be applied to both queries.